# Assigning a char* to a char

Tags: c, pointers, catch2

So I'm very new to C, and I'm just starting to use pointers. I'm using a 2D array to convert a set of strings from hexadecimal to decimal, letter by letter. However, in the process, I have to take the first character of each string, and to do that I'm trying to assign them to a char.
This line specifically is giving me trouble.

```
aChar = input[j][i];
```

It keeps saying I can't convert from const char* to char, but no matter how I change it, I can't seem to get it to work.

Heres the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "catch.hpp"
#include <unistd.h> 
TEST_CASE("Listing 2.2")
{
    int x; 
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    x = 0; 
    const int N = 8;
    char aChar;
    const char* input[N][5] = {"a000", "ffff", "0400", "1111", "8888", "0190", "abcd", "5555"};
    int answers[N] = {40960, 65535, 1024, 4369, 34952, 400, 43981, 21845};
    for (j=0; j>N; j++){
        for(i=0; i>5; i++){
            aChar = input[j][i];
            x = x << 4;                  
            if (aChar <= '9') 
            { 
                x = x + (int)(aChar & 0x0f); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                aChar = aChar & 0x0f; 
                aChar = aChar + 9; 
                x = x + (int)aChar; 
            }
            CHECK(answers[j] == x); 
        }//end for 1
    }//end for 2 
    printf("End of program.\n"); 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` is a 2D array of pointer to characters. Effectively it has 3 dimensions. Two Dimensions of strings of N*5 and the third dimension will traverse the characters in each string.

```
const char* input[N][5]
```

If you want the first character of each string, you need to use

```
aChar = input[j][i][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the culprit:

```
const char* input[N][5] = {"a000", "ffff", "0400", "1111", "8888", "0190", "abcd", "5555"};
```

You want to declare an array to 8 strings of size 5 (4 digits + terminating null) but actually declare an array of 8 arrays of 5 **pointers**.

What you want is:

```
const char input[N][5] = {"a000", "ffff", "0400", "1111", "8888", "0190", "abcd", "5555"};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a 2D array

In order to use a 2D array of `char` you should declare: `const char input[N][5]`. `const char* input[N][5]` is a 2D array of `char*` (instead of an array of strings you get a 2D array of strings).

Given your declaration, no wonder that a `aChar = input[j][i];` results in an assignment of a `char*` to a `char`, which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong condition for your for loops.
You initialized your loop variable (`i/j`) with 0 but you ask for the loops to be terminated if the `i/j`is bigger than `5/N`. 
If you want to iterate over your whole 2 dimensional array it should look like this:
( '<' instead of '>')

```
for (j=0; j<N; j++){
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    //... your code
    }//end for 1
}//end for 2
```

Answer (score 0):

aChar = input[j][i];
In this statement, you are trying to assigning **const pointer address** to **char**,
It is wrong statement.

You need to reference the pointer variable then assign to the corresponding variable, 
Can you change the statement as,
aChar = *input[j][i];